# React Native: How can one Stripe user send payment to another Stripe user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, stripe-payments, reactjs

Stripe has an example ( https://stripe.com/docs/charges ) where I can charge a user, and in return I would be the one receiving the payment. But in React Native, how can one Stripe user send a payment directly to another Stripe user? An example would be extremely helpful.

Will upvote and accept the answer. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) in order to accept payments on behalf of others. Keep in mind that Stripe is not a [money transmission service](https://stripe.com/us/prohibited-businesses#financial-and-professional-services) -- the charges you create must be for the sales of actual goods or services.

Comment: If a buyer is submitting a payment via Stripe, is that how typically marketplace, where users buy and sell each others items, works? Or is there another way to implement the payment exchange amongst users?

Comment: Connect is indeed Stripe's product for marketplaces. Stripe uses different concepts for buyers (customers) and sellers (accounts), but it is definitely possible to create both a customer and an account for the same person or entity so that they can act both as a buyer and a seller.

Comment: Then using Stripe API purely, is it recommended for the platform (acting as a middle-man in this case) to charge the buyer, platform receives the payment, and would send the payment to the seller? Or for buyer to send the payment directly to the seller? And in either case, what information is needed to send the payment to a particular user? Because in the example shown here https://stripe.com/docs/charges , nowhere do I define where I would like the charged payment to go to.

Comment: This is the documentation for creating charges with Connect: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees. For compliance reasons, you must specify how the funds are split between yourself (the platform) and the seller when the charge is created. You can't first create the charge on the platform, then later transfer funds to the seller.

Answer (score 0):

The Stripe API doesn't have react-native support today, so to solve that problem you could create a web system like a Payment Gate way to process your transactions, there you can implement everything you need and use the Stripe Docs to guide you.